# Best way to give feedback to user on submitting a form React-Native

Tags: react-native, forms, user-input, alert

I'm looking for a good way to give positive feedback to the user, so they know when they press 'Submit' that the data they typed in has been registered.

`Alert.alert()` could do it, but Im looking for something they dont have to dismiss/press 'ok' to. Preferably something that dismisses itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more of a design choice, but if you want something that is not intrusive, you can use a [snackbar](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/snackbar.html) or a success/error message under the form.

[image: Snackbar]

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for - thank you! Couldn't find it on Google no matter how I searched.